Missing postback response from Facebook Messenger One-Time-Notification (OTN) Request
I'm currently building a chatbot on Facebook messenger and am struggling with implementing the "one time notification" flow.
I can successfully ask the user if they'd like to receive a notification, but I never receive any pingback on my webhook. I made sure my webhook was subscribed to optin events but still nothing. I also made sure my page had access to the One-time notification feature
I've tried checking the permissions all over my facebook account, figuring it must be a facebook-side error for not sending the response to the webhook, but I can not figure it out. I've also tried implementing this from scratch several times to see if I simply missed a step somewhere but no change.
Page Permissions:

Webhook Subscriptions:

Here's how I'm recieveing the request:
def handle_message(self, request):
    data = request.get_json()
    if data['object'] == "page":
        for entry in data['entry']:
            for messaging_event in entry['messaging']:
                sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
                
                if messaging_event.get('optin'):
                    print('Optin event recieved!!!')
                    token = messaging_event['optin']['one_time_notif_token']

                # Check for postback and handle it
                elif 'postback' in messaging_event:
                    payload = messaging_event['postback']['payload']
                    self.handle_payload(sender_id, payload)
                # Check for quick_reply and handle it
                elif 'message' in messaging_event and 'quick_reply' in messaging_event['message']:
                    payload = messaging_event['message']['quick_reply']['payload']
                    self.handle_payload(sender_id, payload)
                # Handle regular text messages
                elif 'message' in messaging_event:
                    message_text = messaging_event['message'].get('text', '')
                    print("Message from {}: {}".format(sender_id, message_text))
                    response_text = self.chatgpt.get_chat_response(message_text)
                    self.send_message(sender_id, response_text)
    return jsonify({'success': True}), 200

Here's the code of how I'm sending the request:
def send_otn_request(recipient_id, page_access_token):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    data = {
        "recipient": {
            "id": recipient_id
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "one_time_notif_req",
                    "title": "Want us to remind you of your appointment?",
                    "payload": "YES_REMINDER"  # Payload to track the type of notification
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(f"Sending OTN request to recipient: {recipient_id}")
    print(f"Request headers: {headers}")
    print(f"Request data: {data}")

    response = requests.post(
        f'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/me/messages?access_token={page_access_token}',
        headers=headers,
        json=data
    )
    print(f"OTN request response: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
    
    # Check for errors in the response
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error sending OTN request: {response.text}")
    else:
        print("OTN request sent successfully!")

    return response.json()


The OTN postback was successfully sent to the webhook AFTER switching to Live from Development mode.
Not ideal for testing, hope Facebook fixes this soon.
My use case was for appointment notifications so after resolving this, I found the CONFIRMED_EVENT_UPDATE tag was a better fit.
